# Show <div> only if prop is defined

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to show an icon for a React component only if it was defined.
This is my code:

```
export const Button = ({ children, link, icon, background }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={`${link}`} passHref>
      <button
        className={`mt-4 inline-flex px-5 py-3 rounded-xl text-base font-medium text-white ${background} hover:bg-indigo-800 active:bg-grey-900 focus:outline-none border-4 border-white focus:border-purple-200 transition-all`}
      >
        {children}
        {this.props.icon ? <Icon path={`${icon}`} /> : null}
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

But when I run it I get a 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined'
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Akhil: That would produce the same error for the same reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `this.props`?  Your function parameters are destructured into local variables in the function signature:

```
export const Button = ({ children, link, icon, background }) => {
```

And you already use those local variables, including `icon` here:

```
<Icon path={`${icon}`} />
```

So you'd use it exactly as you *already* use it and your other variables:

```
{icon ? <Icon path={`${icon}`} /> : null}
```

Comment: Oh god, yeah, that's right. Thanks for the answer, works now!

Answer (score 1):

You have already destructured the props so there is no need to `this.props.icon`    Just use `icon`

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a react functional component *this*.props is irrelevant.
*this* is for Class components. If you want to learn [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```
export const Button = ({ children, link, icon, background }) => {
```

This Button is A Arrow function (A different way to declare a function) that takes in props as its arguments but you de-structure the props here so you don't have to use props.link, props.children etc.